# How to convert Datetime into only Date format

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
lblAppointmentDate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["AppDate"].ToString();
```

This is my code giving the output as:

> AppointmentDate: 11/19/2014 12:00:00 AM.

I want only Date as `19/11/2014`.

Comment: `lblAppointmentDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["AppDate"]).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");`

Comment: Perfect Answer Abbath..

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date however you like.

Use ToString() on the DateTime and pass in the appropriate format string.

Try one of the format strings from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
someDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format it like following. Before that don't forget to convert to `datetime` type. Following is just an example only.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```